# Hiding other ids when read more of a particular id is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have various read more buttons under each staff details in my about.html which will direct to their particular sections in another page. i have about.html where i have displayed the staff images, excerpt description and a read more button. Full description of each staff can be red from the bio.html where i have entered the complete description.

When read more button of say id #bio1 is clicked it will be linked to http://www.mysite/bio.html#bio2 . i want all the other ids to be hide in this case(#bio2, #bio2, #bio3 and so on)

HTML CODE

```
<li>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img_block wrapped_img">
            <img src="img/pictures/team1.jpg" alt="Tom" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel_title">
            <h6>Dave</h6>
            <div class="op">Chair Person</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel_desc">
            <div class="exc">Saul Yarmak has the distinguished honor or repeating his role as Chairman of BXI.</div>
            <div class="read_more">
                <a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I believe you can use a onClick JS function and Display:none; all the Elements you want to hide. for instance document.getElementById("carousel_title").style.display="none";

Comment: Do you want to remove evenhandler from other buttons ?

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on `#bio1` hide all elements with particular class and show only `#bio1`:

```
<span id='bio1' class='a'></span>
...
<span id='bio8798' class='a'></span>


$(document).on('click', '.a', function(){
    $('.a').hide();
    $(this).show();
})
```

Comment: i tried    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".read_more1").click(function(){
  $("#bio2").hide();
  $("#bio3").hide();
  $("#bio4").hide();
 });
});
</script> but not working

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to the links and use jquery `not()` as shown here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwMP7/)**

```
$('.myLink').click( function() {    
    $('.myLink').not(this).css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

This will make all elements of class `myLink` invisible - except the one that has been clicked (`this`) . If you want to remove from the layout then you would use `hide()` rather than `css('visibility','hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

give you bio elements a class name "bio". then do the following to hide them all:

```
$(".bio").hide();
```

after that show your selected bio:

```
$("#bio6").show();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/hide/ and http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

If on click of button (`#bio1`), redirects to another page then I don't think there is a use for hiding other buttons.

Since page is already redirected to another page/section.

### Update:

Now you can do this using **[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**,

```
var bioVar = $("div[id^='bio']");
bioVar.on("click", function() {
    bioVar.not(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Sine the contents in some of the bio is very less, other bios description also is visible in the page and it doesnt look good